# How do I get multiple lines to print after ending this logical loop

Tags: c

Me again. The C rookie. I am working on an assignment to write a program that prompts a user to enter info after which the program should list back out the data that was entered. My code only prints the last record info that is entered.

For example, I enter the following info for employee #1 "Rookie Coder" as the first employee name and enter 25 and 40 for hourly wage and hours worked, respectively. Then, I enter the following info for employee #2 "Slow Learner" as the 2nd employee name and enter 20 and 45 for hourly wage and hours worked, respectively. The program only `prints` the info related to "Slow Learner". But I want to print out the info for both records entered.

Can someone please offer guidance on what I'm missing to get both records to print? Thank you from the C Rookie

```
// C Libraries Used

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// Constant declerations

const float OTPAYFACTOR = 1.5;
FILE *userinputfile;                  //disk file (for input)

// Variable declerations
char deptname [21];
char firstname [10];
char lastname [10];
char fullname [21];
float hrsworked;
float hrwage;
int count;
char again;

// Function Prototypes


// M A I N   F U N C T I O N

int main (void){
    printf("Mountain Pacific Corporation\nDepartment Salary Program\n\n");
    printf("Please enter the name of the department: ");
    scanf("%s", &deptname);
    count = 0;    // Initialize this "counting" variable to zero to start
    printf("\n");
    count = 0;    // Initialize this "counting" variable to zero to start
    printf("\n");
   do {

      count++; // Increment the counting variable

      printf("Enter employee #%d: ", count);
      scanf("%s %s", &firstname, &lastname);
      strcpy(fullname, firstname);
      strcat(fullname, " ");
      strcat(fullname, lastname);
      printf("Enter the hourly wage of %s: ", fullname);
      scanf("%f", &hrwage);
      printf("Enter total number of hours: ");
      scanf("%f", &hrsworked);

      printf("\nThank you. Process another employee? ");
      scanf ("%s", &again);
      printf("\n");

} while (again != 'N' && again != 'n');

      printf("End of processing.");

    printf("%s, $%0.2f, %0.2f: \n", fullname, hrwage, hrsworked);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by slow learner?

Comment: @NinjaCoder, I have a hard time learning without good examples :(

Comment: regarding: `const float OTPAYFACTOR = 1.5;`  the value is being declared as a `float`, but the literal is a `double`.  Suggest: `const float OTPAYFACTOR = 1.5f;`   Note the trailing 'f' in the literal value

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful (read the MAN page for details)  2) when using the '%s' format specifier, always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input field.  Because '%s' and '%[..]' specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids buffer overflow (which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.)

Comment: these two lines: `count = 0;    // Initialize this "counting" variable to zero to start
    printf("\n");` are repeated twice in succession..  Probably only want them in the code once, not twice.

Comment: regarding: `scanf ("%s", &again);`  the variable `again` is only a single character (remember the automatic appending of a NUL char).  Suggest: `scanf (" %c", &again);`   Notice the leading space in the format string to consume any leading 'white space',  Notice the use of the '%c' specifier (which only inputs a single character and does not have any automatic appending of a NUL byte.

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nThank you. Process another employee? ");`  this does NOT inform the user as to what a valid input would be.  Suggest: `printf("\nThank you!  Enter 'n' to exit or any other key to all another employee. ");`

Comment: regarding: `printf("\n");`  when outputting a string, with no formatting, best to use: `puts("");`   Note: the function: `puts()` always appends a newline to its' output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one set of variables that you use on each iteration of the loop.  Anything stored the first time through the loop is overwritten the second time through the loop.  So you'll only ever store the most recently entered set of values.

You want to declare each of the variables that are taking data as an array, that way you can save multiple values.

```
char deptname [5][21];
char firstname [5][10];
char lastname [5][10];
char fullname [5][21];
float hrsworked[5];
float hrwage[5];

...

do {

      printf("Enter employee #%d: ", count+1);
      scanf("%s %s", &firstname[count], &lastname[count]);
      strcpy(fullname[count], firstname[count]);
      strcat(fullname[count], " ");
      strcat(fullname[count], lastname[count]);
      printf("Enter the hourly wage of %s: ", fullname[count]);
      scanf("%f", &hrwage[count]);
      printf("Enter total number of hours: ");
      scanf("%f", &hrsworked[count]);

      printf("\nThank you. Process another employee? ");
      scanf ("%s", &again);
      printf("\n");

      count++; // Increment the counting variable

} while (again != 'N' && again != 'n');
```

Then you need to loop through the array to print each element:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    printf("%s, $%0.2f, %0.2f: \n", fullname[i], hrwage[i], hrsworked[i]);
}
```

Comment: I've done just that but it doesn't seem to work. What should the printf read?

`
    printf("End of processing.\n");
    printf("%s, $%0.2f, %0.2f \n", fullname[count], hrwage[count], hrsworked[count]);

return 0;
}`

Comment: @davidw You're only printing a single element of each array.  That element also happens to be past the last one you wrote to, so you won't see anything meaningful.  You need to loop through the arrays and print each one.  See my edit.

Comment: Do you offer tutoring :)

Comment: now I'm trying to calc some derived values based on the data entered but I don't seem to get anything back. What do I miss? Here's what I wrote.

`if (hrsworked[count] <= REGWORKWKHRS){
reghrsworked[count] = hrsworked[count];
othrsworked[count] = 0;
otwage[count] = hrwage[count] * OTPAYFACTOR;
grosswage[count] = hrwage[count]*reghrsworked[count];
}
else{
reghrsworked[count] = REGWORKWKHRS;
othrsworked[count] = hrsworked[count] - REGWORKWKHRS;
otwage[count] = hrwage[count] * OTPAYFACTOR;
grosswage[count] = reghrsworked[count] * hrwage[count] + othrsworked[count] * otwage[count];
}`

Comment: this statement: `} while (again != 'N' && again != 'n');` will not stop the user from overrunning the available buffer arrays.  Suggest: `} while (count < 5 && tolower(again) != 'n');`   Note: `tolower()` is found in the `ctype.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

:) naive from your side but don't worry. You are storing **only the last** data into the `fullname, hrwage, hrsworked`, so only the last output is saved there. You need a better **data structure** to store the data as they are inserted by user.

**1)** If you know how many inputs there will be you can use a predefined array of strings for strings for the name and floats for the hours and wage.

**2)** if you don't know then you will need an scaling data structure like for example a list in order to put/add/append elements to it ;)

for **C Arrays** check [this](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Arrays.html)   and for **Lists in C** check [this](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-linked-list/)

Then last but not least after you fill them with the input you just need to loop with a for / while loop in order to print the array or list.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

remove the `&` symbol from below statement because `deptname` itself is string

```
scanf("%s", &deptname);
```

do same  from below statements also

```
  scanf("%s %s", &firstname, &lastname);
```

you want to print all records but at last there is only one printf so obviously it prints only last employee records

```
printf("%s, $%0.2f, %0.2f: \n", fullname, hrwage, hrsworked);
```

if you wants to prints all employee data after giving 'N' option, you should store information before that, my suggestion is **put all entries inside structure** and then take **array of structure** and store every time.